# Publish Message to IOT Hub - Eclypse Paho MQTT

Tags: c, azure, mqtt

Below is my code for connecting and sending data from device to cloud using Eclypse Paho MQTT Library. I am able to connect with IOT Hub as rc results 0 in my case but It doesn't send message to my IOT Hub device. Can anyone please guide me where I have made mistake or what I am doing wrong ?
I am using Visual studio 2015 with .Net framework 4.0 and eclipse-paho-mqtt-c-windows-1.0.3 libraries

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "MQTTAsync.h"

#if !defined(WIN32)
#include <unistd.h>
#else
#include <windows.h>
#endif

#if defined(_WRS_KERNEL)
#include <OsWrapper.h>
#endif

#define ADDRESS     "ssl://xxxxx.azure-devices.net:8883" //tcp://localhost:1883"
#define CLIENTID    "EnergyMeter" //"ExampleClientPub"
#define TOPIC       "devices/EnergyMeter/messages/events/" //"MQTT Examples"
#define PAYLOAD     "Hello World!"
#define QOS         1
#define TIMEOUT     10000L

volatile MQTTAsync_token deliveredtoken;

int finished = 0;

void connlost(void *context, char *cause)
{
    MQTTAsync client = (MQTTAsync)context;
    MQTTAsync_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTAsync_connectOptions_initializer;
    int rc;

    printf("\nConnection lost\n");
    printf("     cause: %s\n", cause);

    printf("Reconnecting\n");
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        finished = 1;
    }
}


void onDisconnect(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
    printf("Successful disconnection\n");
    finished = 1;
}


void onSend(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
    MQTTAsync client = (MQTTAsync)context;
    MQTTAsync_disconnectOptions opts = MQTTAsync_disconnectOptions_initializer;
    int rc;

    printf("Message with token value %d delivery confirmed\n", response->token);

    opts.onSuccess = onDisconnect;
    opts.context = client;

    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_disconnect(client, &opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start sendMessage, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


void onConnectFailure(void* context, MQTTAsync_failureData* response)
{
    printf("Connect failed, rc %d\n", response ? response->code : 0);
    finished = 1;
}


void onConnect(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
    printf("hello");
    MQTTAsync client = (MQTTAsync)context;
    MQTTAsync_responseOptions opts = MQTTAsync_responseOptions_initializer;
    MQTTAsync_message pubmsg = MQTTAsync_message_initializer;
    int rc;

    printf("Successful connection\n");

    opts.onSuccess = onSend;
    opts.context = client;

    pubmsg.payload = PAYLOAD;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = strlen(PAYLOAD);
    pubmsg.qos = QOS;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;
    deliveredtoken = 0;

    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_sendMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start sendMessage, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MQTTAsync client;
    MQTTAsync_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTAsync_connectOptions_initializer;
    int rc = 5;
    int a;
    a = MQTTAsync_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID, MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
    printf("a is %d", a);
    printf("Hey");
    MQTTAsync_setCallbacks(client, NULL, connlost, NULL, NULL);
    printf("check1\n");
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 5;
    //conn_opts.username = "ssl://Ironman.azure-devices.net/stark";
    //conn_opts.password = "SharedAccessSignature sr=Ironman.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fstark&sig=eoAum3Hl2gWWiFVJT%2FhmUMwYH4NFAT%2B5fG8tRTm%2BbaA%3D&se=1558677763";
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
    printf("check2\n");
    conn_opts.onSuccess = onConnect;
    conn_opts.username = "CCMSIoTHub.azure-devices.net/EnergyMeter/api-version=2016-11-14";
    conn_opts.password = "SharedAccessSignature sr=xxxxxxx.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2FEnergyMeter&sig=undNm%xxxxxxxxz87I%3D&se=xxxxxxxxx";
    printf("check3\n");
    conn_opts.onFailure = onConnectFailure;
    conn_opts.context = client;

    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("rc is %d ", rc);
    }
    printf("Waiting for publication of %s\n"
        "on topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n",
        PAYLOAD, TOPIC, CLIENTID);
    while (!finished)
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64)
        Sleep(100);
#else
        usleep(10000L);
#endif


    MQTTAsync_destroy(&client);
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++?  It looks like C.

Comment: Yes, It is C...

Comment: @ParthDesai Did you find any solution? Even i got stucked because of same issue

Comment: @Candy yes I have solved you have to use Baltimore as Root CA Certificate. if wanted I can mail you sample code for reference

Comment: @ParthDesai If you could answer your question that will be helpful or can you please mail me some reference.

Answer (score 3):

Below Code works fine In my case

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "MQTTClient.h"
#define ADDRESS     "ssl://xxxxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net:8883" //tcp://localhost:1883"
#define CLIENTID    "xxxxxxxxxx" //"ExampleClientPub"
#define TOPIC       "devices/xxxxxxxxxx/messages/events/" //"MQTT Examples"
#define PAYLOAD     "Hello World!"
#define QOS         1
#define TIMEOUT     10000L
volatile MQTTClient_deliveryToken deliveredtoken;
void delivered(void *context, MQTTClient_deliveryToken dt)
{
    printf("Message with token value %d delivery confirmed\n", dt);
    deliveredtoken = dt;
}
int msgarrvd(void *context, char *topicName, int topicLen, MQTTClient_message *message)
{
    int i;
    char* payloadptr;
    printf("Message arrived\n");
    printf("     topic: %s\n", topicName);
    printf("   message: ");
    payloadptr = (char *)message->payload;
    for (i = 0; i<message->payloadlen; i++)
    {
        putchar(*payloadptr++);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    MQTTClient_freeMessage(&message);
    MQTTClient_free(topicName);
    return 1;
}
void connlost(void *context, char *cause)
{
    printf("\nConnection lost\n");
    printf("     cause: %s\n", cause);
}
#define TEST_SSL
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MQTTClient client;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
    MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
    int rc;
    rc = MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
        1, NULL);
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
    conn_opts.username = "xxxxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net/xxxxxxxxxx/api-version=2016-11-14";
    conn_opts.password = "SharedAccessSignature sr=xxxxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fxxxxxxxxxx&sig=undNm%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=15xxxxxx";

#ifdef TEST_SSL
    MQTTClient_SSLOptions sslOptions = MQTTClient_SSLOptions_initializer;
    sslOptions.enableServerCertAuth = 1;
    sslOptions.trustStore = "D:/Parth/Projects/MQTT/MQTT Sample D2C Azure IOT Hub Tested Program/rootCA.crt";
    conn_opts.ssl = &sslOptions;
#endif

    //conn_opts.ssl->trustStore = "D:\Parth\Projects\MQTT\paho.mqtt.c-master\test\ssl\test - alt - ca.crt";

    rc = MQTTClient_setCallbacks(client, NULL, connlost, msgarrvd, delivered);
    if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pubmsg.payload = PAYLOAD;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = strlen(PAYLOAD);
    pubmsg.qos = QOS;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;
    deliveredtoken = 0;
    MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &token);
    printf("Waiting for publication of %s\n"
        "on topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n",
        PAYLOAD, TOPIC, CLIENTID);
    while (deliveredtoken != token);
    MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
    MQTTClient_destroy(&client);
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. It helped me in solving my issue